# How to remove class and ID attributes from HTML using Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, attributes

I want to remove all **class** and **ID** attributes from HTML by using Simple HTML Dom Parser. I'd like to remove those attributes throughout the entire HTML DOM, regardless of the type of tag. Throughout the HTML doc, there are various tags (li, p, div, etc.) that are being styled based on the CSS selector, and I basically want to remove the styling. Is there a way to traverse the entire DOM without specifying tags to remove all the Class/ID attributes?

Comment: Are you happy with a jQuery solution?

Comment: And do you want to remove _all_ classes and ids from all tags?

Comment: Is it possible to do it without jQuery and use Simple HTML Dom only? Yes, I'd like to remove all classes and ids from all tags. Thanks

Comment: I'm still waiting to see if it can be done with only Simple HTML DOM. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it would be something like:

```
foreach ($html->find('*[id], *[class]') as $element) {
    $element->id = null;
    $element->class = null;
}
```

https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_find
https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_access